# Convert phone number "+2125551212" to format "(212) 555-1212" using Twilio SDK

Tags: java, sms, twilio

I have a phone number stored as a string String in the format `+12125551212`.  Using the Twilio SDK (if possible) I would like to convert that phone number into a String in the more friendly format of `(212) 555-1212`.

Here's how one could do it using `com.google.i18n.phonenumbers`

```
String phoneNumber = "+12125551212";
try {
  Phonenumber.PhoneNumber parsedPhoneNumber = phoneUtil.parse(phoneNumber, "US");
  phoneNumber = phoneUtil.format(parsedPhoneNumber, PhoneNumberUtil.PhoneNumberFormat.NATIONAL);
} catch (NumberParseException e) {
  logger.error("Error parsing phone number {}", phoneNumber);
}
```

Is there something similar in the Twilio SDK?

(I'm hoping for a non-regex, non-string-manipulation Twilio-specific answer, if it exists.)

Comment: Are you having issues? This is a very trivial thing to do... Did you read the API of Twilio? If it's not there, just write some code to do it. It's probably a 2-3 lines.

Comment: My question is can it be done with the Twilio SDK, not how to do I parse a String using Java.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider I've update the question for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can do that and much more using [Twilio's Lookup API](https://www.twilio.com/lookup). You will find the API documentation [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/lookups).

Here's a full working example of how you would format a telephone number using the API.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.twilio.Twilio;
import com.twilio.rest.lookups.v1.PhoneNumber;

public class Lookup {
  // Find your Account Sid and Token at twilio.com/user/account
  public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
  public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "your_auth_token";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);

    PhoneNumber number = PhoneNumber
        .fetcher(new com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber("+15108675309"))
        .setType("carrier")
        .fetch();

    System.out.println(number.getNationalFormat());
  }
}
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: This is def what I was looking for, however is this a "carrier" lookup that costs $0.005 per call, or is it a free "format" lookup, Marcos?

Comment: If you don't specify anything on the type (by just removing `.setType` completely) it defaults to null, and is therefore free. 

Answer (score -1):

https://twilio.github.io/twilio-java/

Go to PhoneNumber, it has a method called Get National Format and also look at PhoneNumber.Type that might be what you're looking for.

Otherwise I would just use string indexing + parsing, and create a utility function that converts nationalToUS or USToNational etc.